# developing iOS and Android native apps

Tags: android, ios

I need to develop a native app both on iOS and Android. It is a small app, more like a learning application - however, I do intend on publishing it on both markets. And I do not wish to use PhoneGap/Titanium/..., but would rather develop on core platforms as this gives me access to all the functions I need.

Since the functionality is the same on both platforms (obviously), I was wondering what the best approach would be. Should I develop on Android and then port to iOS? Or reverse? Or develop in parallel?

I guess there is no way I could reuse some of the code? For instance if I developed in C?

How should I handle code updates? Should I keep a separate bug list for each platform and fix them independently?

Comment: This would be better asked on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), especially the code updates / bug report stuff.

Comment: Truth be told, I wasn't aware of this (yet another ;) SE programming site. And even after checking FAQs on both sites I still don't know why would this question be a better fit for one versus the other.

Comment: It is a bit fuzzy. Stack Overflow tends to skew more towards code questions, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you want a perfect app you should write separate code for each OS. One in Java for Android and second one in Objective-C for iOS. Of course, you can program core in C++ for iOS (don't know if you can do this in Java) and it is fine.

You should start developing to a platform which you consider yourself as more experience programmer. Once when you finish your app it will be easier to copy your ideas to different language.

Comment: With the Android NDK you can also use C++ on Android :).  However (especially UI stuff) some stuff can only be done in Obj-C on iPhone and Java on Android, though that list is slowly shrinking.

Comment: Agree, but as i said: App core/model can be written in C++. And i don't see the point to draw user interface with C++. In iOS is extremly simple, so if you have well designed application you don't spend much time drawing olny View

Comment: Thanks SimpleMan, sounds like a good advice.